# Problems with parsing a JSON object with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

My php file does this:

```
<?php include('connection.inc.php'); ?>
<?php header("Content-type: application/json"); ?>
<?php

    $sth = mysql_query("select * from ios_appointments a join ios_worker w join ios_partners p where a.workerid_fk = w.workerid and w.partnerid_fk =  p.partnerid and p.code = 'DEMO6003'");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

It returns this JSON output:

```
[{"appointmentId":"25","start":"2013-01-07 14:45:00","end":"2013-01-07 15:45:00","workerid_fk":"1","userid_fk":"22","isActive":null,"workerid":"1","prename":"Sarah","lastname":"Gonzalez","avatar":"megan.jpg","lineup":"Herren\/Damen","languages":"DE EN","partnerid_fk":"6","partnerid":"6","code":"DEMO6003","partnerName":"Demo Partner","street":"bla 1","zipCode":"bla","city":"bla","workers":"n\/a","email":"test@test.com","phone":"+41414441111","slogan":"Demo Partner zum Erkunden der App"},{"appointmentId":"26","start":"2013-01-10 11:15:00","end":"2013-01-10 12:15:00","workerid_fk":"1","userid_fk":"22","isActive":null,"workerid":"1","prename":"Sarah","lastname":"Gonzalez","avatar":"megan.jpg","lineup":"Herren\/Damen","languages":"DE EN","partnerid_fk":"6","partnerid":"6","code":"DEMO6003","partnerName":"Demo Partner","street":"bla 1","zipCode":"bla","city":"bla","workers":"n\/a","email":"test@test.com","phone":"+41414441111","slogan":"Demo Partner zum Erkunden der App"}, ...]
```

Now I try to parse the JSON output in a html file with this script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $.getJSON('<link to php file>', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, appointment) {
                alert('entered each()');
                var id = appointment.appointmentid;

                console.log('appointmentid ' + id);
            });
        });
  </script>
```

`$.getJSON` is called, but `data` is `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Have you debugged in the console to ensure you are receiving the response correctly?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load <link to php file>. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` what does it mean?

Comment: @dooonot it means that you're trying to get content from a domain that's different than the page you're starting from.

Comment: Actually it means it's trying to get content from the origin `null`, which is *technically* not the same domain you're on points more likely to some value not being set as expected.  Not sure where that error is coming from though if it gets into `getJSON`

Comment: Also instead of `alert()` I prefer `console.log(variable)` for debugging so I have the data at a glance without having to close a hundred popups.

Comment: Are you loading the file locally and not via a web server?

Comment: Yes it is loaded locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to capitalize the `i` in `appointment.appointmentid`;

```
appointment.appointmentId; // <-- since your property has it capitalized
```